# Do I need to upload a build to Itunes Connect in order to test IAP

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I've integrated the unity IAP service into my project. It works on Android and both win and mac editors. When I build for iOS The initialization of the purchasing fails because no products were found. I've followed the unuty provided guide and I have created a sandbox test user and added the product with the same ad in the app page.

Comment: Please check your inapp ID on appstore. Is it giving any warning about metadata missing or something like that?

Comment: @bisma yes! how is that relevant ?

Comment: If there is some issue with the inapp product id, it will not work. Fulfil the requirment and inapp purchase should be "Ready to Submit"

Comment: @bisma the product id is the same as in the code and the status is "Ready to Submit" but I still get the same error that no such product exists.